# How to add custom log handler to Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java.util.logging

I am trying to add a custom log handler to my java application. I have implemented a InnerLogger class that extends java.util.Logging.Handler class. And in my logging.properties declared as a handler:

```
handlers:com.mycompany.util.InnerLogger
```

But when I launch the development sever, I got the following error:

```
Can't load log handler "com.mycompany.util.InnerLogger"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.util.InnerLogger
```

I can add my custom handler to loggers one by one ,but I just wondering is there a way to add it to all loggers.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Issue 11499: Allow custom loggers for Java AppEngine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11499)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to add a `Handler` to the root `Logger` when my application initializes. You can put this code in a warmup task or servlet filter.

```
private static Logger LOG;

...

LOG = Logger.getLogger("");
LOG.addHandler(myCustomHandler);
```

Its not as graceful as using logging.properties, but it is an adequate workaround when running on GAE.

Comment: This worked for me, although it ended up creating duplicate logging statements because I merely called LOG.addHandler(myCustomHandler).

To fix that, you could remove the existing handlers returned from LOG.getHandlers(), and then add your custom handler.

Comment: +1 Is the work-around still necessary as of GAE 1.9.1 and do we know the technical reason why the setting in logging.properties is ignored?

Answer (score 2):

It might not the solution you were looking for, but have you considered using [Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)](http://www.slf4j.org/) in your application instead of using directly JUL?

Comment: This is what I end up doing, using SLF4J with Log4J and a custom appender.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void addStreamHandler(){

    // TODO check if appCode has X length
    CustomHandler handler = new CustomHandler();
    LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    Enumeration<String> e = manager.getLoggerNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()){

        Logger logger = manager.getLogger(e.nextElement());
        if ( logger.getName().startsWith("com.google"))continue;
        logger.addHandler(handler);
        System.out.println(logger.getName());
    }
    System.out.println("***finished*****");
}

public static void removeStreamHandlers(){

    LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    Enumeration<String> e = manager.getLoggerNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()){

        Logger logger = manager.getLogger(e.nextElement());
        Handler[] handlers = logger.getHandlers();
        for ( int i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++){
            Handler h = handlers[i];
            if (h instanceof CustomHandler){
                logger.removeHandler(h);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```