# Setting up GetSentry.com with Java on Google AppEngine

Tags: java, sentry, raven, google-app-engine

I have been trying to set up logging to getsentry.com on Google AppEngine using Java.

I have tried using their projects at https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java. Specifically I have tried setting up java.util.logging (JUL) with their [raven](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven) module, and adding appengine support using [raven-appengine](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven-appengine).

**I would like to know if anyone knows of a way to set up getsentry with appengine?** Below is *some* of what I have tried.

Using the configuration `logging.properties`:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler

net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler.level=WARNING
net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler.dsn=https://<user>:<password>@app.getsentry.com/<some number>
net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler.ravenFactory=net.kencochrane.raven.appengine.AppEngineRavenFactory

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
```

then the development server says that the class `net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler` cannot be found. The question [How to add custom log handler to Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841172/how-to-add-custom-log-handler-to-google-app-engine) says to load it in code instead. So I tried  that, but all sorts of accesses into the logging framework are disallowed by Google. So I abandoned this as well.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Have you resolved this?

Comment: No :( I have opened an issue, but haven't got any answer. Maybe you could ask there too? https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/issues/122