# How to format log info in single line in Google app engine Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am using logger in google app engine as below:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestServlet.class.getName());
log.info("Debug1 Here");
```

In my terminal it is displayed two info lines as below:

```
[INFO] Feb 07, 2015 1:34:27 PM com.my.app.TestServlet doPost
[INFO] INFO: Debug1 Here
```

The first line is system generated.
For every log statement it displays two lines.

So how can I make it to display these two lines in single line somthing like this:

```
[INFO] Feb 07, 2015 1:34:27 PM com.my.app.TestServlet doPost> Debug1 Here
```

Also how will I code if I don't want the first line (i.e. system genreated) to be displayed?

Note: I am using java.util.logging.Logger

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what logger are you using? log4j, commons-logging, jul, slf4j?

Comment: I am using java.util.logging.Logger

Comment: Did you look at the javadoc? Handler looks promising. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841172/how-to-add-custom-log-handler-to-google-app-engine.